# passing a string to a function to get used as an object in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a loop that calls a `JSON` array as an object. I want to itterate through the array to find items called match, the match names are called - match1, match2 etc.

It works instead of using the created `var` `finalM` `i` type `match1, match2` etc.

```
    var theObject = data; // get json data 
    var i;
      for (i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++){
          var add = i + 1 ;
          var finalM = "match"+ add; 
          $('.someDiv').append(
              theObject[i].finalM.someVal
          );
    }
```

I know its something to do with the scope of the string, but can't find a good example to help me with the problem.

Comment: can you please share the `theObject`

Comment: a fiddle demo would be good.

Comment: @Manish: Better yet, Stack Snippets right here on site.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that would be good. i was basically asking for a demo thats it. be it a fiddle or stack snippet.

Comment: It's kind of funny since you already know how to use a variable to access a property: `theObject[i]`.

Comment: @Manish will make one for next time, i just didn't understand the syntax of  the string to object in a looped array, smarx was right. will be answering correct shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
$('.someDiv').append(
    theObject[i][finalM].someVal
);
```

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this type of question/answer as this is a very commonly asked question/answer.